# Evitar Registros duplicados en un select sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola recientemente estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto con `SQL Server`, y dentro de la base de datos hay registros duplicados.

Quiero realizar una consulta `select` para cargar los registros en una tabla, pero que esta no me muestre registros duplicados.

Esta es mi consulta `TSQL`:

```sql
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DP.fecha_creacion desc) as indice,
        DP.cod_peso
        ,DP.cod_temporada
        ,DP.cod_variedad_rotulada
        ,DP.valor_peso_neto
        ,DP.peso_neto_inf
        ,DP.peso_neto_sup
        ,DP.estado
        ,DP.fecha_creacion
        ,DP.fecha_modificacion
    FROM dev_auto_pesos as DP
```

Comment: puedes usar la clausula distinct que como su nombre indica solo trae los que no son iguales, select distinct ...

Comment: Cual es el campo que no puede estar duplicado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El escenario:

```
Create table dev_auto_pesos (
         cod_peso tinyint
        ,cod_temporada tinyint
        ,cod_variedad_rotulada varchar(10)
        ,valor_peso_neto tinyint
        ,peso_neto_inf tinyint 
        ,peso_neto_sup tinyint
        ,estado tinyint
        ,fecha_creacion datetime
        ,fecha_modificacion datetime
        );
```

Insertamos datos:

```
Insert into dev_auto_pesos
( cod_peso 
, cod_temporada 
, cod_variedad_rotulada 
, valor_peso_neto 
, peso_neto_inf  
, peso_neto_sup 
, estado 
, fecha_creacion 
, fecha_modificacion 
)
values
(1,1,'a',1,1,1,1,'20210101','20210101'),
(1,1,'a',1,1,1,1,'20210101','20210101'), -- completamente igual
(1,2,'a',1,1,1,1,'20210101','20210101'),
(1,3,'a',1,1,1,1,'20210101','20210101'),
(1,3,'a',1,1,1,1,'20210101','20210101'), -- completamente igual
(1,3,'a',1,1,1,1,'20210201','20210101'),
(1,1,'b',1,1,1,1,'20210201','20210101'),
(1,1,'b',1,1,1,1,'20210201','20210101 10:08'); -- mínimo cambio
```

Aquí la pregunta es **¿Qué significa repetidos?**.

Las filas identificadas como *--completamente igual*, o también la que es idéntica a la anterior, salvo que una de las columnas tiene otra hora.

Los tratamientos son diferentes:

**Opción1:** Totalmente igual

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DP.fecha_creacion desc) as indice,
         DP.cod_peso
        ,DP.cod_temporada
        ,DP.cod_variedad_rotulada
        ,DP.valor_peso_neto
        ,DP.peso_neto_inf
        ,DP.peso_neto_sup
        ,DP.estado
        ,DP.fecha_creacion
        ,DP.fecha_modificacion
    FROM dev_auto_pesos as DP
    group by   DP.cod_peso
        ,DP.cod_temporada
        ,DP.cod_variedad_rotulada
        ,DP.valor_peso_neto
        ,DP.peso_neto_inf
        ,DP.peso_neto_sup
        ,DP.estado
        ,DP.fecha_creacion
        ,DP.fecha_modificacion;
```

[image: Resultados]

También sería perfectamente válido utilizar distinct desde un cte o tabla derivada.

```
with cte as (
Select distinct 
        DP.cod_peso
        ,DP.cod_temporada
        ,DP.cod_variedad_rotulada
        ,DP.valor_peso_neto
        ,DP.peso_neto_inf
        ,DP.peso_neto_sup
        ,DP.estado
        ,DP.fecha_creacion
        ,DP.fecha_modificacion
    FROM dev_auto_pesos as DP
)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fecha_creacion desc) as indice,
         cod_peso
        ,cod_temporada
        ,cod_variedad_rotulada
        ,valor_peso_neto
        ,peso_neto_inf
        ,peso_neto_sup
        ,estado
        ,fecha_creacion
        ,fecha_modificacion
    FROM cte;
```

**Opción 2**: Casi iguales

Cuando una columna tiene valores similares en varias filas, debemos de utilizar una función de agrupación. En el caso del ejemplo voy a escoger la función máx para devolver la fecha mayor de las que hay, y así elimino el registro que tiene como hora 00:00, quedándome con el de las 10:08

```
SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DP.fecha_creacion desc) as indice,
             DP.cod_peso
            ,DP.cod_temporada
            ,DP.cod_variedad_rotulada
            ,DP.valor_peso_neto
            ,DP.peso_neto_inf
            ,DP.peso_neto_sup
            ,DP.estado
            ,DP.fecha_creacion
            ,max(DP.fecha_modificacion)
        FROM dev_auto_pesos as DP
        group by   DP.cod_peso
            ,DP.cod_temporada
            ,DP.cod_variedad_rotulada
            ,DP.valor_peso_neto
            ,DP.peso_neto_inf
            ,DP.peso_neto_sup
            ,DP.estado
            ,DP.fecha_creacion;
```

[image: Resultados max fecha]

Ahora ya no tenemos 6 filas, sino 5, porque de la que era casi igual, comparada con su "hermana", hemos obtenido la que tiene la fecha de modificación mayor como valor para juntar ambas filas en una.

[Distinct vs group by](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct)

[Group by](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/group-by-quizas-la-clausula-mas-conflictiva/)

Comment: De verdad te lo agradezco mucho! me ha funcionado gracias